# IP Black List TcpServer

Tags: delphi

How i can limit the connections per ip? i've tried this code [how to block unknown clients in indy (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421799/how-to-block-unknown-clients-in-indy-delphi) but if my server is flooded i can't connect. the code from Remy just prevent CPU to use 100% and use more ram. but the connection from flood still alive on tcpserver and i can't connect to server. so my question is, how i can limit the connection before onconnect, something on accept using tcpserver? maybe hook accept function and try limit the connection ?

Comment: You're probably best off to block incoming connections on your hardware level, such as in the firewall. If your problem is an attacker overloading your server, then it wouldn't matter how much code you write, that data still technically is making its way into your application. After all, that's the nature of how DDoS works.

Comment: yes, i writed a small app who only create 9999 clients and connect and that freeze my system. so i need limit the connection per ip without use firewall.

Comment: To extend my prior comment, there are many hardware firewalls which are explicitly designed to prevent DDoS attacks of this exact nature. Most standard / cheap routers can't handle it. I even tested DDoS on a business class SonicWall router, which supposedly had DDoS prevention - a friend in the UK only spent 3 seconds of attacks before I lost internet and I had to go upstairs and physically reboot it.

Answer (score 6):

> How i can limit the connections per ip?

You already know the answer to that, as that is exactly what [the other code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421799/) is doing.

> if my server is flooded i can't connect.

The purpose of the other code is simply to limit a client IP address to a max of 10 simultaneous connections, not to prevent flooding or lower CPU/RAM usage. You can't stop unwanted clients from connecting to your server, unless you deactivate the server, or set its `MaxConnections` property.  Outside of that, about all you can do is disconnect unwanted clients as soon as possible, which you can do in the server's `OnConnect` event. But if you are getting flooded, that is going to take time to process, especially if you are continuously locking and unlocking the server's `Contexts` list, which will end up serializing the server's internal threading.

Flood management really needs to be handled by a firewall or router/load balancer, not in the server app itself. If this is not acceptable to you, then at least on Windows only, an option might be to write a custom `TIdServerIOHandlerStack`-derived component that overrides the virtual `Accept()` method to call WinSock's [`WSAAccept()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513.aspx) function, which offers a callback you can use to reject connections before they leave the accept queue, and thus they will not be seen by `TIdTCPServer`.  For example:

```
type
  TMyServerIOHandler = class(TIdServerIOHandlerStack)
  public
    function Accept(ASocket: TIdSocketHandle; AListenerThread: TIdThread; AYarn: TIdYarn): TIdIOHandler; override;
  end;

function MyConditionFunc(lpCallerId, lpCallerData: LPWSABUF; lpSQOS, lpGQOS: LPQOS; lpCalleeId, lpCalleeData: LPWSABUF; g: PGROUP dwCallbackData: DWORD_PTR): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  if (the address stored in lpCallerId is blocked) then
    Result := CF_REJECT
  else
    Result := CF_ACCEPT;
end;

type
  TIdSocketHandleAccess = class(TIdSocketHandle)
  end;

function TMyServerIOHandler.Accept(ASocket: TIdSocketHandle; AListenerThread: TIdThread; AYarn: TIdYarn): TIdIOHandler;
var
  LIOHandler: TIdIOHandlerSocket;
  LBinding: TIdSocketHandle;
  LAcceptedSocket: TIdStackSocketHandle;
begin
  Result := nil;
  LIOHandler := TIdIOHandlerStack.Create(nil);
  try
    LIOHandler.Open;
    while not AListenerThread.Stopped do
    begin
      if ASocket.Select(250) then
      begin
        LBinding := LIOHandler.Binding;
        LBinding.Reset;
        LAcceptedSocket := WSAAccept(ASocket.Handle, nil, nil, @MyConditionFunc, 0);
        if LAcceptedSocket <> Id_INVALID_SOCKET then
        begin
          TIdSocketHandleAccess(LBinding).SetHandle(LAcceptedSocket);
          LBinding.UpdateBindingLocal;
          LBinding.UpdateBindingPeer;
          LIOHandler.AfterAccept;
          Result := LIOHandler;
          LIOHandler := nil;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LIOHandler);
  end;
end;
```

Then you can assign an instance of `TMyServerIOHandler` to the `TIdTCPServer.IOHandler` property before activating the server.

Comment: i have this error with your code [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(372): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IOHandlerSocketClass'

Comment: now is [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(1682): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TIdServerIOHandler' and 'class of TMyIdServerIOHandler' when try assign IdTCPServer1.IOHandler := TMyIdServerIOHandler;

Comment: @DouglasRuiz the `TIdTCPServer.IOHandler` property is a pointer to an object, not a class type. You have to `Create` a `TMyIdServerIOHandler` object before you can assign it: `IdTCPServer1.IOHandler := TMyIdServerIOHandler.Create(IdTCPServer1);`

Comment: i have this error Cannot access protected symbol TIdSocketHandle.SetHandle on LBinding.SetHandle(LAcceptedSocket); line :/ i'm using delphi 10.1 berlin

Comment: i added the code IdTCPServer1.IOHandler := TMyServerIOHandler.Create(IdTCPServer1);, and some messages on function accept but my connection never fire the message :/ so my connection dont pass by accept function

Comment: @DouglasRuiz: `Accept()` is the function that actually takes a client out of the backlog and creates a new socket for it.  `TIdTCPServer` can't operate without it.  So the only way `Accept()` would not be called is if either 1) you are not `override`ing it (which my example does), or 2) no clients are being put in the server's backlog to begin with.

Comment: i tested with a flood tool that creates various connection in a infinite loop and application crash after some time, using a ip filter onconnect and onexecute prevent application from crash but no one can connect while tcpserver are being flooded :/ so the better solution is use a firewall. bcs on delphi we can do nothing :(

Comment: just other litlle question, you think are good use only onexecute with a protocol to manage connect/disconnect and messages from client to server? or use onconnect, ondisconnect and onexecute. because i find uDGProtocol from Dorin Duminica and he only use onexecute to manage all informations, like connect, disconnect, messages in a small protocol that he created.

Comment: How retrieve the ip on lpCallerId ?